# How to get data geoip in Laravel 4?

Tags: geolocation, laravel, laravel-4, geoip

I use Laravel 4 for my project, I need to know the geolocation of users, however, when I make mistakes in syntax, Laravel displays data GeoIP like (GEOIP_COUNTRY_NAME, GEOIP_CITY...)

I want to know how i can get the data geoip in my script?

Thanks.

Comment: "When I make mistakes in syntax"? Can you provide snippets of your code? I don't think you problem is related to Laravel.

Comment: no, i don't have a problem in my script, laravel display some information about geolocation(geoip) when i get the error, i want to use this information for my website.

Comment: Can you show the code that generates the error, and the error?  I can't say I've seen that info in any error message Laravel has generated for me.

Comment: Here is a screenshot, this is the information that i want: [link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bw-_6ukExs8hRUV0b24zLUdncDQ/edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for are items available in the `$_SERVER` PHP variable.  I believe that they are only available if `mod_geoip` is enabled in Apache.